# Writing and reading data from Cassandra 3.9

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

I am very new to cassandra and from database background. I want to know the process/tools/utilities by which I can load bulk of data into cassandra column family and read the data to show for analytics.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The commands you talk to cassandra keyspaces (which are what databases are to sql) are similar to sql.
Check the [CQL query language turorials](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCommandsTOC.html).

Also check the [datastax cassandra tutorials](http://www.datastax.com/resources/tutorials) or the ones at [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/), but check that what you read matches the version you want to use.
Once you get a hang of the basics you can move on to cassandra-specific concepts like [data replication](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html) and [partitioning](http://www.datastax.com/resources/tutorials/partitioning-and-replication)
A quick & easy start would be to get [cassandra on docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/) and setup a container running your keyspace.